# Word for "disqualifier"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that would mean "disqualifier" if "disqualifier" were a word?

Alternatively, let's say someone presents a list of qualifiers

1. x
2. y
3. z

and says you do not qualify if any of them apply to you. I would call these "disqualifiers" but apparently that is not actually a word. What is the right name for them?

Comment: The government, while not the model of intelligence, uses disqualifier on many official documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd stick with *disqualifier*, as its meaning quite obvious in context.  And there are several dictionaries that list it, including [MSN Encarta](http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?lextype=3&search=disqualifier) and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disqualifier).

Answer (score 1):

The following words may be used:

1. rejection (as in rejection criteria)
2. elimination
3. recusal (used in judicial parlance)
4. debarment - a rather strong use, implying disqualification from future attempts
5. preclusion - used from the perspective of the candidate

All in all, disqualifier is the best word as it is context-free.

Answer (score 0):

The words you list are qualifiers that don't apply to you.

*Disqualifier* is not a word I find in the NOAD; the closer word I can find is *disqualify* (the verb), which means "to declare someone not eligible for an office or activity", and it cannot be used in the sense you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

**Impediment** would be used in a legal context, but in everyday terms has the looser sense of *hindrance* rather than *disqualifier*.

Answer (score -1):

In your context, the word you really mean could be 'exception'. Rather than use a double negative of first stating what qualifies and then using its absence as the criterion, it is better to list the 'exceptions', at least for the sake of clarity.